# Append json based on key value

Tags: json

I have 2 json data and i want to join both based on same key .

Input :

```
resp1 = [{"data1": col1 ,"b": col2} , {"data2": col3 ,"c": col4}]

resp2 = [{"data1": col1 ,"d": col5} , {"data2": col3,"e": col7}]
```

Output :

```
resp = [{"data1": col1,"b": col2,"d": col5} , {"data2": col3,"c": col4,"e": col7}]
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Neither your "Input" nor your "Output" is valid JSON or JavaScript, `{}` denotes an object, so the outer level of that is incorrect. Did you mean to use `[]` at the outermost level to indicate an array?